# Issues with updating chart with chart.update()

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to update my chart data using chart.update().  In this case, my chart variable is called `scatterChart`:

```
scatterChartData.datasets[0].data.push({ x: +xx, y: +yy });
  console.log(scatterChartData.datasets[0]);
  window.scatterChart.update();
```

This code is supposed to run when I click a button.  However, it doesn’t work.  What am I missing?  The full project can be seen at http://next.plnkr.co/edit/McN3qxt5caOZr77M

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0):

In window.onload function add:

`window.scatterChart = scatterChart`

Comment: What is this supposed to do for me?

Comment: In coordFunc you call window.scatterChart, but it is undefined, that's why your code doesn't work. You need to define window.scatterAlert

Comment: So now it is `window.onload = function() {
  window.scatterChart = scatterChart..`.  However when I click the button the graph is still empty.  Also previously, I just used scatterChart.update but that didn't work either.  I appreciate your help!